# TCP send() is blocking

Tags: linux, network-programming

I am running an application in which I am using TCP blocking socket. TCP `send()` is blocked, but `netstat` is showing send and `recv Q = 0`.

Can someone suggest why would `send()` be blocked?

Comment: I assume you already did a successful blocking `connect()`?

Comment: yes. bind() and connect() already did as blocking.

Comment: Did you successfully send data previously on the same connection, or does it block on the very first send?  What is the receiving program like?

Comment: We are able to successfully send data on same connection, but after some number of iterations it is getting blocked.

Comment: In that case I strongly recommend using tcpdump to capture the exact traffic and analyze in detail from the beginning what is happening on the connection.

Comment: if you are able to send for a short while, before blocking starts, I would assume that the peer end is not reading yet. Maybe the peer end is trying to send you data as well and are blocked for the same reason

Comment: Okay... Thank you all for the clarification!!!

Answer (score 0):

The two reasons I can think of would be:

- The receiving program keeps the socket open but does not read the data. In this case when the receiving socket buffer would become full, the sender could not send any more, it's socket send buffer would fill up and send() would block.
- The network connection between the sender and the receiver is completely blocked after you initially connect. This would result in the sender socket typically failing after a timeout, also this would usually not be repeatable.

Neither case exactly agrees with your netstat results, but from experience I'd say tcp send() does not block unless the socket send buffer is full.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification!!